# ¿Cómo validar solo algunos campos con Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Solo quiero validar dos inputs con Bootstrap; actualmente valido todo el formulario con la clase 'needs-validation', sin embargo solo necesito que realice la validación a dos campos.

```
<form name="modal" id="form_Modal" autocomplete="off" method="POST"
id="formulario" class="needs-validation" novalidate >
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row align-items-center pb-1">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label for="labelnombre" class="col-form-label">RUT:*</label>
            </div>
             <div class= "col-7">
                <input type="text" id="proveedorrut" name="proveedorrut" class="form-control" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                   Valor invalido
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="row align-items-center pb-1">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label for="labelnombre" class="col-form-label">Nombre:*</label>
            </div>
             <div class= "col-7">
                <input type="text" id="proveedornombre" name="proveedornombre"           
class="form-control" required >
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                   Valor invalido
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

        <div class="modal-footer">   
            <button type="submit" class="btn text-light" id="guardar" style="background color:#7aae2f;" >Guardar
cambios</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>

</form>
```

Ese es todo el código HTML.

Y ese es el código js por defecto de bootstrap para validar el formulario completo; he intentado cambiar algunas cosas pero ninguna me funciona. ¿Cómo podria cambiar el código js para que solo valide los dos primeros campos y siga mostrando el diseño por defecto de bootstrap?

Comment: no, es un formulario que contiene alrededor de 20 campos entre inputs y select, sin embargo solo necesito validar esos campos, los cuales que agregue a la pregunta

Comment: Buenas, he intentado ejecutar tu codigo pero me es imposible dado que no esta completo. Aun asi, eliminando los required de los campos que no quieres validar no te funciona?

Comment: Buenas, con los required si funciona, sin embargo me estan solicitando que haga una validacion de campos proveniente de bootstrap, con la clase 'needs-validation' y el uso de 'invalid-feedback', el tema es que dentro de la documentacion de bootstrap solo se señala la validacion de un formulario completo, y yo solo necesito la verificacion de esos dos campos unicamente, y en ese punto quedo , ya que nose de que forma puedo verificar solo esos dos y darle uso a la verificacion del 'invalid-feedback' de bootstrap.

Comment: Agrega un [example] indicando cuales serían los campos a validar

Answer (score 0):

dado que necesitas usar bootstrap te propongo lo siguiente.
HTML tiene un atributo llamado `formnovalidate` el cual se añade al final del input e independiente que tenga el required no se validara.
En bootstrap tienes la opcion de añadir la clase `class= "form-control-novalidate"` la cual tendra la misma funcion que la mencionada anteriormente.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: No, no ha funcionado.De todas formas muchismas gracias por la ayuda